# Text Box width to inherit from table td

Tags: html, css, textbox, css-tables

I am trying to have a text box width be the same as its parent's table cell.

Applicable CSS is as follows:

```
input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #3c6f91;
    font: 9pt arial, tahoma, verdana sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
}

.gv {
    border: solid #3c6f91 1px;
}

.gv td {
    border: solid #3c6f91 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The table is rendered from ASP.NET GridView with the following:

```
<table class="gv" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="cph_cphPCR_gv" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: What Happens]

This is what I am trying to do:

[image: What I Want]

The second image is when the table gets stretched out to when it does not fit on the screen.
I tried `width: auto;`, `width: inherit;`, `table-layout: fixed;`, searched quite a lot for an answer but was not able to find an answe. I am pretty sure, this is not a margin/padding issue...

**EDIT**: http://jsfiddle.net/cN24t/
The first table, when it is wider that the screen, this is how I'd like the textboxes' width to be

Comment: You've set cellspacing to zero but not cellpadding.

Comment: It is set by asp. Anyway, I added cellpadding="0" but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
.gv td {
    border: solid #3c6f91 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table class="gv" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" rules="all" border="1" id="cph_cphPCR_gv" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
```

You could also try using a [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) in the future to help rid yourself of the inconsistencies.

Comment: This made no difference

Answer (score 0):

In tables column width sets automatically by content, `width:100%;` here isn't good option. I suggest set strictly text-area size in pixels. BTW, textarea can be resized by user, and possible, can waste your design. So, I suggest set for textarea: `width`, `min-width` and `max-width` in pixels.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, fixed width is not an option here... Also, I am not using textarea, I am using `<input type="text">`